# Stretch a video without keeping its aspect ratio in C#

Tags: video, aspect-ratio, stretch

I have been trying to code a program displaying videos and I want the video to stretch to the screen so I tried it with

`axWindowsMediaPlayer1.stretchToFit = true`

the video is stretched but the problem is it still keeps the video's aspect ratio
How do I make the video stretch without keeping the aspect ratio?
anyone got a solution to this? been trying to solve this problem for hours
please help!!!

Comment: Take a look at my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749181/stretch-video-of-axwindowsmediaplayer-without-maintaining-aspect-ration-in-c-sha/55842239#55842239