# Stretch video of AxWindowsMediaPlayer without maintaining aspect ration in C#

Tags: c#, .net, axwindowsmediaplayer

Using the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` I need to stretch a video to take up the entire screen. The issue with `stretchToFit = true`, is that `stretchToFit` maintains the aspect ratio of the video, creating blackbars if the video or monitor is not of the same ratio. I do not want these black bars. I do not want to maintain the aspect ratio when I stretch the video.

I have been looking for an answer to this problem for a long time and have read countless questions posed by others. As far as I can tell, no one has any solution.

*I am posting this question despite there being an [exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497478/stretch-a-video-without-keeping-its-aspect-ratio-in-c-sharp) already posted since the other question was posted a year ago with no answers.

Comment: You are trying to do something that doesn't make sense.  So it isn't supported.

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense. VLC supports stretching a video w/o preserving the original aspect ratio. This is useful if a video is 16:8.95 and you want to stretch to remove the black from the 0.05. (This question just came to my attn again due to a notification.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMP doesn't allow stretching of the video without maintaining the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3):

> I do not want these black bars. I do not want to maintain the aspect ratio when I stretch the video.

Here's a solution! Even in `Windows Media Player` and `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` controls with `K-Lite Codec Pack` (**MEGA PACK only**, because it's the only pack which comes with `ffdshow video decoder`). In the `K-Lite Codec Pack MEGA` setup installation process select `Advanced` and go `Next`, **IMPORTANT:** in `Preferred video decoder` switch to `ffdshow video decoder` I also recommend you set `ffdshow audio decoder`, then proceed with `Next` until you finish installation, so now you have `ffdshow video decoder` installed and `Windows Media Player` also `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` controls will use it. After installation go to `ffdshow video decoder configuration`, you can locate it at:

Start Menu Folders > `K-Lite Codec Pack\Configuration\ffdshow video decoder`

Then tick the following settings:

[image]

So now videos will be rendered without keeping aspect ratio that will remove those "black bars" and get stretched to window.

**EDIT:** Just a reminder that a few video formats such as mkv will use by default the `ffdshow video decoder` in `Windows Media Player` and `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` components, other formats Windows 7/8.x/10 use its own codecs for decoding so for that reason you need to go to:

Start Menu Folders > `K-Lite Codec Pack\Codec Tweak Tool`

Then tick your desired settings, here's an example:

[image]

[image]

For more info about Media Foundation, take a look at: http://www.codecguide.com/windows7_preferred_filter_tweaker.htm